# Adding object to array also adds 'null'

Tags: php

I send the following data to my php file via ajax:

```
JSON.stringify({test1: '1', test2: '2'})
```

I would like to write this data to my JSON FILE `content.json` containing an empty array

```
[]
```

I only want to add the content though if it is not there, yet. This is my PHP code:

```
$jsonStringObject = file_get_contents("php://input");
  $phpObject = json_decode($jsonStringObject);
  $newJsonStringObject = json_encode($phpObject);
  header('Content-Type: application/json');

  $jsonString = file_get_contents('content.json');
  $data = (array) json_decode($jsonString, true);

  if (in_array($phpObject, $data) === false){
    $data[] = $phpObject;
  }
  $newJsonString = json_encode($data);
  file_put_contents('content.json', $newJsonString);
```

It almost works. Something is wrong with the way the data is added to the array because when I call the function for the first time, it updates content.json to

```
[null,{"test1":"1","test2":"2"}]
```

On calling the function again, it adds the object again despite the if-statement:

```
[null,{"test1":"1","test2":"2"},{"test1":"1","test2":"2"},{"test1":"1","test2":"2"}]
```

Can anyone help me to spot the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing apples and oranges (or rather objects to arrays).

Make sure you decode all json as arrays:

```
$jsonStringObject = file_get_contents("php://input");
// Added true as second argument to get it bas as an array
$phpObject = json_decode($jsonStringObject, true);

$jsonString = file_get_contents('content.json');
// Removed the (array) since the second argument literally means "return as array"
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);

if (in_array($phpObject, $data) === false){
    $data[] = $phpObject;
}

$newJsonString = json_encode($data);
file_put_contents('content.json', $newJsonString);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/rnCn5